# How can line code polarity inversion happen?

Tags: communication, error, polarity, encoding

One of the disadvantages of some line codes like NRZ-L or RZ is that if a sudden change in polarity occurs, then all received bits will be erroneous (flipped).

- How can such a sudden change in polarity occur in practice?
- And is it really a problem?

Comment: U are thinking of NRZ-I and this was invented by IBM in 1956 for mag tapes and is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks. Are you implying that polarity inversion is not a problem anymore? I know NRZ-I, and I gave NRZ-L as an example of a line code that is affected by polarity inversion. I am asking about the inversion itself and how it may happen. So are you saying that it is not an issue anymore?

Comment: I was saying glitches inverting polarity only occurs in NRZ-I while -L is simply binary code and that -I is obsolete

Comment: I wouldn't say NRZ-I is obsolete, at all. Isn't it in use, for example, by USB?

Comment: Regardless if they are obsolete or not. My understanding is that NRZ-I almost solves the problem because only one bit will be erroneous unlike NRZ-L.

Comment: almost solving a problem is *not* solving the problem, so I'd argue this is a bit of a senseless point of view; what would solve this is channel coding.

Comment: The advantage of NRZ-I ( & @MarcusMüller  I stand corrected) is that if you invert the Apple connector and get the correct decoding. Error detection like any scheme protects integrity.

Comment: “Still” get correct USB decoding....typo ... on the Lightning connector.

Comment: @osmak you said that you just wanted to wait to see if someone contradicts my "under realistic circumstances it doesn't happen". For a month, nobody contradicted. So, I presume my answer would be worth accepting, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can such a sudden change in polarity occur in practice?

In a wireless/bandpass channel, that'd be a 180° phase shift.

I've never seen that occur anywhere on a wired (baseband signaling) link that you'd use NRZ-whatever on, and aside from "blatant bugs in the hardware design", I wouldn't see how this would occur in practice.

> and is it really a problem?

Not that I can think of, no.

Even if we came up with a model where we get polarity reversals, they'd be "worst case" errors (our whole line code being designed the fact that the two levels are as strongly *not* the other as possible, you'd need the maximum physical error to achieve that) – and hence rare (otherwise our line code choice would have been bad, and we should have used a physical layer that is robust against these).

Rare errors on links are typically countered either by checksums and re-requesting broken frames, or by forward error correction. Of the latter, you can definitely devise a scheme that converts a continuous bit flip starting at specific position to a single bit error, which might be well-recoverable with the given code. However, this would have little to do with the line coding.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95257/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-muller-how-can-line-code-polarity-inversion-happe).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).